# Resize Parent Fancybox from within iframe link

Tags: iframe, resize, fancybox

I need to resize from 800x300 to 700x400 when a user clicks a link within a Fancybox iframed page.. but had no success yet. Please post as much code (inc. html) please... if possible :)!

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Why don't you post yourself what you have tried and we eventually correct your mistakes ?

Comment: I found this (http://www.amitpatil.me/fancybox-runtime-resizing-of-iframe/), but it doesn't work in Google Chrome... any suggestions on modifications? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
parent.$('.fancybox-inner').height(400);
parent.$('.fancybox-inner').width(700);
```